# Drop-down folder shortcut in the dock

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

Do you know a way to do this ? Or something like it ? (Ubuntu 20.04 ~ GNOME 3.36)

[image: Drop-down folder shortcut in the dock]

Is there a script, a tweak, or extension doing it?
Would it be possible with GNOME Shell Extensions ?

Comment: Someone recommended me Files Menu : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/907/files-menu/